# Command-Line Way to Make Update Notifier Check Daily

Tags: command-line, updates, update-manager, configuration, gsettings

Is there a way to make the update notifier check for updates daily (like you could in *Software & Updates*) from the command line or by editing a file? I checked the GSettings schemas, but didn't find any keys that change values if I change the frequency in the graphical menu, so I don't think it's any of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update Notifier *already* checks daily.

It's an apt systemd timer. It runs at a different random time each day.

In this example, you can see that apt-daily (which runs `sudo apt update`) ran 4:24 ago, and will run again in 1:37.

```
$ systemctl list-timers apt-daily.timer
NEXT                        LEFT          LAST                        PASSED       UNIT            ACTIVATES        
Tue 2020-10-13 22:15:09 CDT 1h 37min left Tue 2020-10-13 16:12:52 CDT 4h 24min ago apt-daily.timer apt-daily.service
```

- **Randomization**: The randomization evens out the load on the mirrors. Those mirrors are storage and bandwidth volunteered by organizations worldwide -- be very nice to them.

  The random time is set by a line in `/lib/systemd/system/apt-daily.timer`. You can disable it and set a specific daily time, but remember to be a good neighbor: Don't hammer mirrors by picking a common time. If possible, leave the randomization alone. It works.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to update your system, you can place the following in `/etc/cron.daily/update.sh`, or `/etc/crontab` and set to run as root user:

```
apt update && apt upgrade -y
```

If you want to use a GUI application, you can simply call `update-manager`, which will prompt for a password when run.

### EDIT

user535733's answer is obviously more accurate, but I'll leave this here in case someone wants to manually call the GUI updater.